# What word is used to describe always using words that mean the extreme?

Tags: adjectives, hyperbole

I'm trying to think of the word that is used to describe someone who always uses words that mean the most or least of a trait (like best, worst, fastest, slowest, brightest, smartest, etc. etc.). I thought there was a word to describe this category of adjectives, but I can't think of it!
Thanks!

Comment: Are you thinking of [*superlatives*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/superlative?), perhaps?

Comment: The examples given are all superlatives, but that's because they have a superlative morpheme (_-st_) attached to their end. Superlatives are one type of Polar predicates, which, like comparison, can only take place when there is a continuous scale of characteristics, like _boiling - hot - warm - tepid - cool - cold - freezing_. In this scale, the endpoints (or "poles") _boiling_ and _freezing_ are the polar predicates in the list. They have interesting semantics; for instance, only polar predicates can be modified by _absolute(ly)_: _absolutely freezing/boiling/_ but *_absolutely hot/cold_.

Answer (score 2):

The category of adjectives is [*superlatives*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superlative), after *positive* and *comparative*.

Overuse of such words, leading to sensationalisation, may be ***hyperbole.***

> Exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally
>
> [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hyperbole)

> It was the best day ever!
>   Only the crumbliest, flakiest chocolate...™
>   There were millions of them!

The statements are *hyperbolic.*