# What is the word to describe using the phrase "no one" when you actually mean "most people"?

Tags: terminology

Example:

> **No one** would ever do that.
> Most people wouldn't do that

Comment: Not a single person would ever do that.

Comment: Attributed to Yogi Berra: "Nobody goes there... it's too crowded"

Comment: The 2 sentences are equivalent, because there is a negation in "wouldn't ". Using "Most people" instead of "No one" followed by the same verb+object would be a *misconstruction*.

Comment: @Graffito — They aren’t equivalent. *No one would do* means people doing = 0. *Most people wouldn’t do* means people doing > 0. For “equivalency” you’d need something like *few people would do* or *not many people would do*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Technical term for an outrageous exaggeration](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/467283/technical-term-for-an-outrageous-exaggeration) Or [What word is used to describe always using words that mean the extreme case](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/372877/what-word-is-used-to-describe-always-using-words-that-mean-the-extreme/372879#372879)?

Comment: Do you mean *sarcasm* or *irony*?  Mike: Who on earth would attempt to keep a pile of gold coins they'd dug up when plowing their field?   Tom: Right, no one would ever do that.

Answer (score 5):

Substituting *no one would* for *most people wouldn’t* is a form of the rhetorical device called *hyperbole*:

> Hyperbole is a figure of speech and literary device that creates
> heightened effect through deliberate exaggeration. Hyperbole is often
> a boldly overstated or exaggerated claim or statement that adds
> emphasis without the intention of being literally
> true. . . .
>  <sub>Source and read more: [Literary
> Devices — *Hyperbole*](https://literarydevices.net/hyperbole/)</sub>

Comment: Variants of this question appear millions of times on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth — I disagree. While the answers to the questions you linked are the same, the questions themselves are not. OP would need to have framed/understood *no one would* for *most people wouldn’t* as an exaggeration in the first place. But polarity got in the way — and that is what is interesting about this question.